# dangerouslyGetParent() returns undefined from child screen of Tab Navigator

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I call `this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent()` from a child screen of a BottomTabNavigator, I get `undefined`. I am certain this tab has a parent, yet why is this happening? I am trying to save settings at the Tab navigator level and pass these settings to children screens. The only child that can change these settings is the SettingsScreen.

This is the code:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default class MyTabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>

    );
  }
```

Settings Screen:

```
export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {evenLicensePlate:null}
  }


  saveSettingsButton = () =>{
    this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent() // <- is undefined

  }
```

Comment: Do you have fully code? I can access navigation from my screen successfully. Maybe you need update your package version?